# Cannot import function from module despite trying a lot of answers

Tags: python, import, module, importerror, python-packaging

I tried:

- using realtive and absolute imports,
- adding `__init__.py` to all folders,
- adding the root directory to path using sys.path.insert and also export PYTHONPATH,

but nothing seem to work! I am not able to import functions from sibling directory. I don't know what else can I try to make it work. I am not sure if the fact that I am running this as streamlit application via `streamlit run Main.py` makes any difference? The structure is as follows:

```
application
├── models
│   └── model1.py
└── streamlit
    ├── Main.py
    └── pages
        └── page1.py
```

and I want to import `function1` from `model1.py` into `page1.py`

The `model1.py` file has structure as follows:

```
def function1():
    print('hello from module1')

def some_other_function():
    ... 

def some_other_function2():
    ... 

def main():
    some_other_function()
    some_other_function2()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If the `application` folder is in sys.path, then `from models import model1` should work.

Comment: It is in sys.path. `from models import model1` works, but when I try to call a function from model1 like `model1.function1()` it gives me the error 'AttributeError: module 'models.model1' has no attribute 'function1'

Comment: In that case, the obvious answer is that `model1.py` does not, in fact, contain that function.  Show us that module.

Comment: similarly when I try just to import a function like `from models.model1 import function1` it gives: 'ImportError: cannot import name 'function1' from 'models.model1''

Comment: and same for all the other functions in the file

Comment: Edit the question to include `model1.py`.

Comment: I edited the question to specify the structure of the file from which I am importing. It does contain a function with the name I am trying to import.

Comment: _It does contain a function with the name I am trying to import_ The error message `ImportError: cannot import name 'function1' from 'models.model1'` means that the module _was_ found and imported successfully, but there is no importable item in the module named `function1`.  The only way we can help further is if you show us that module.

Comment: According to your posted contents of `model1.py`, that import statement ought to have worked.  Therefore your real code must differ, somehow, from what you have posted.  My only advice is to doublecheck everything in your post to make sure it exactly matches your real code.

Comment: Run this code and see what it prints: `from models import model1; print(dir(model1))` This should print out a listing of every variable and function that is defined inside `model1.py`.  Hopefully this will give you a clue as to what you did wrong.